# Implementing Sumif functionality in R on iris dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

The given one line gives me a vector with three species of iris dataset in R. I want to dynamically find the sum of all the sepal.length's corresponding to each of the species "setosa","versicolor" and "virginica", without hard coding it, and represent the three sum values as a vector. Please help.

```
emp = unique(iris$Species)
```

Answer (score 0):

dplyr should be able to accomplish this. see below:

```
library(tidyverse)

emp <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: we are stuggling with this post, kindly check and suggest a possible fix, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987238/overcoming-the-issue-of-na-values-without-hard-code-to-create-plotly-charts

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple to generate the aggregate for one or all columns using dplyr.

```
iris %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>% 
 summarise_all(sum)


 Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
   <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
  setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```

Comment: kindly suggest some solution with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987238/overcoming-the-issue-of-na-values-without-hard-code-to-create-plotly-charts